# Python turtle onkeypress doesn't work in my laptop.. what's wrong with it?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, onkeypress

Hi I'm a student in South Korea and today I got a problem in my Python class.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFfWO.png)

```
import turtle
import math

def turnleft():
    player.left(50)

def turnright():
    player.right(50)

def fire():
    x = player.xcor()
    y = player.ycor()

    velocity = 80

    angle = player.heading()
    vx = velocity * math.cos(angle * 3.14 / 180) #각도 -> 라디안
    vy = velocity * math.sin(angle * 3.14 / 180)

    while player.ycor() >= 0:
        vx = vx
        vy = vy - 10
        x = x + vx
        y = y + vy
        player.goto(x, y)

player = turtle.Pen()
player.shape("turtle")
screen = player.getscreen()

screen.onkeypress(turnleft, "Left")
screen.onkeypress(turnright, "Right")
screen.onkeypress(fire, "space")

player.goto(300, 0)
player.goto(-300, 0)
player.goto(-300, 300)
player.goto(-300, 0)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJwRJ.png)

So this is a code that I learned today, and it's an exactly same code as my administrative assistant's one. It worked well in his computer, so it means there's nothing wrong with it but when I try to move a turtle in my laptop it doesn't work at all. Left, Right, space key all of them.. what do you guys think is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

probably you forgot to say `turtle.listen()` if you post the source code it would be better.

Note: Don't forget the

```
while True:
     Turtle.update()
```

I usually write `turtle.listen()` on top of `while True:`